# G is a group, H is a subgroup of G, and N a normal group of G. Prove that N is a normal subgroup of NH.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I have already proved that NH is a subgroup of G. To prove that N is a normal subgroup of NH I said the we need to show $xNx^{-1}$ is a subgroup of NH for all $x\in NH$

Or am i defining it wrong?

Answer (score 3):

To show $N$ is a normal subgroup of $NH$, you can show that $x Nx^{-1} = N$, where $x \in NH$.

That is, if $xNx^{-1} = N$, where $x \in NH$, then $N$ is a normal subgroup of $NH$.

**HINT:** you can use what you know about $N$ being normal in $G$, and the fact that $H \leq G$ to your advantage here.

Comment: Thanks, @Amzoti: I can only hope, or wait... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of showing it is a subgroup, but really a subset. That is, $H\lhd G$ if for each $g\in G$ $$gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$$

---

You have to show that for each and $x\in N$, $g\in NH$ it is true that $$gxg^{-1}\in N$$

But if $g\in NH$, $g=wy$ where $w\in N$,$y\in H$. Thus, what is to be proven is $$wyxy^{-1}w^{-1}\in N$$

But $N$ is normal, so $yxy^{-1}\in N$, say $=u$. Since $w\in N$, it is immediate that $wuw^{-1}\in N$, so that $N\lhd NH$.

Answer (score 0):

For any subgroup $K$ of $G$ with $N \subset K \subset G$, you can show that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $K$. Also, you can easily show $N \subset NH$.